# Can't get bar chart colors in Chart js working in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, chart.js2

This is my first time working with Chart Js and I managed to get it displaying on my page but the keys 'label', 'backgroundColor', 'borderColor', and 'borderWidth' won't display. The keys 'labels' and 'data' work just fine as I can see the labels and the bars in the chart. I tried assigning the non-displaying keys to variables just like 'labels' and 'data' to see if it would work that way but no luck. I also tried passing hex colors and regular color names like red, blue, etc. but that didn't work either. If anyone could provide some assistance it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';

var Chart = require("react-chartjs").Bar;

class BarChart extends Component {

  capitalize(name) {
    return name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
  }

  render() {

    var pokeLabels = this.props.stats.map((label) => {
      return this.capitalize(label.stat.name)
    })

    var pokeDataSet = this.props.stats.map((set) => {
      return set.base_stat
    })

    console.log(this.props.stats);

    var data = {
      labels: pokeLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Pokemon Stats',
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,          
            data: pokeDataSet
        }
      ]
    }

    return (
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-offset-0'>
          <Chart data={data} width="600" height="250" redraw />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }   

}

export default BarChart;
```

Comment: Can you add more details to this question please - like how's your react code looking like.

Comment: I posted the contents of the entire file, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I was able to get the colors working by doing this:

```
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: ["rgba(0,10,220,0.5)","rgba(220,0,10,0.5)","rgba(220,0,0,0.5)","rgba(120,250,120,0.5)" ],
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)", 
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: pokeDataSet
        }
```

Hope this can help someone who has a similar issue!

Comment: Yes it did! Thanks mate! :D
`fillColor` = `backgroundColor`, `strokeColor` = `borderColor`, `highlightFill` = `hoverBackgroundColor` and `highlightStroke` = `hoverBorderColor`.

Comment: FYI and anybody that would fall on the same issue, this doc can help: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v1.1.1/docs/02-Bar-Chart.md

Answer (score 0):

The background color will change the color of the bars.

So, you can give different colors to different bar.

```
datasets: [
          {
        label: 'My First dataset',
        backgroundColor: ['rgba(0,10,220,0.5)', 'rgba(220,0,10,0.5)'],
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
        data: pokeDataSet,
          },
    ],
```